# How to write unit test in different files in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am writing a unit test for node application. All my unit tests are in a single file called test/index.ts. I want to separate each test into different files. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: please add your code, at least part of it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, generally you could just duplicate your file and when you run tests you will notice that each runs twice, unless your test command specifies a file, not a directory.

So you just need to create a new file in the test directory and populate it like the first.

If you tell me what command you use to run tests I can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Just move some tests to a different file. Make sure you use describe() and it() in the new file. Then, let's say your tests are in `tests` folder, you can run mocha with `mocha tests/**/*.ts`(assuming ts extension). This will run all files with ts extension in tests folder.